# Simple way of calling a Machine Learning Python script from Excel with out using add-ins

Tags: python, vba, machine-learning

I am stuck in a major pickle where I have some automation in VBA in Excel and need to pass a list of words to a Python script that is running a machine learning algorithm (where it classifies a request). This script will provide a string output (request category) that I need to receive in VBA again.
I have walked through countless methods of using pyxll or xlwings but unfortunately, these will not work for me as the excel file and python file will be in SharePoint being used by different members and I am sure all of them will not be having these add-ins installed.
I found a method of passing the argument (list of words) to a test Python script using command line. The test Python script is able to receive it. Here is the code sample

```
import sys
script_name = sys.argv[0]
text= sys.argv[1]
print('text - ',sys.argv)
```

But when I try to use the machine learning script, let's say, to read and export a dataset then it does not work.
My ultimate goal is to run 2 python function:

1. a function to train my classifier
2. a function that takes this list of words from VBA, runs the predictive algo and gives back the output (a string).

Can someone maybe help me with it? This is the first time I am working with something cross-platform. If it helps my ML algo is running perfectly well in the Python environment, it is the connection with VBA that needs to be sorted out.

FOR EXAMPLE:
I wrote a test script to see if I can pass my request to Python script and then the python script loads a dataset (to see if this functionality is working or not) and creates a file and writes something in it.
Here is the VBA code:

```
Sub SampleCall()
'declare var
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    Dim PythonArg As String, oCmd As String

    'create a new shell obj
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    'provide the file path to the python exe
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\I547565\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"""

    
    'provide file path to python script
    PythonScript = """C:\Users\I547565\SAP SE\Headcount Control Tower for Services - Headcount Control Tower\Control Tower - Automation\Resources\Artificial Intelligence\rough.py"""
    
     PythonArg = "I love Europe"
     MsgBox PythonArg
     objShell.Run PythonExe & Chr$(32) & PythonScript & Chr$(32) & PythonArg
End Sub
```

ANd here is the python script:

```
import sys

script_name = sys.argv[0]
text= sys.argv[1]
print('text - ',sys.argv)
input('press enter to continue...')

from pathlib import Path
sysPath = str(Path.home())
rawDataPath = sysPath + "\folder\XRdata.xlsx"
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('XRdata.xlsx', sheet_name='data')
print(df.head())

f= open("output.txt","w+")
f.write('category')
f.close()
input('press enter to close...')
```

If I run the python script independently, i get a file named output.txt in my folder. But when I run this script from VBA, I am able to see the "I love Europe" on the console but the rest of the code does not give me the output that is the txt file is not generated.
Please help before I rip my hair out!!!

Comment: Just to add the code sample is to accept the inputs from vba to python and this gives the output. But if I try to run my .py file for ML this way the command prompt flashes and closes with no output

Comment: Would it be an option to use a light / portable database (SQLIte?) to hold the intermediate content.

Comment: I could maybe write the output to a file. That would work. getting arguments to python and from python is not a big issue. Problem is as sson as a have to work with dataframes the same code does not produce the output

Comment: Ok. Please *update the question* to further explain the issue(s) you’re having with DataFrames.

Comment: It is not giving an issue, it simply not running. Let me add an example that I am trying to run